# Can't find the supervisor file in Hue folder

Tags: hue

I can't find the file 'supervisor' in Hue folder. According to official documentation it should be in the folder $HUE_HOME/build/env/bin. I am doing my operation in Ubuntu server 22.04. My objective to send queries to Impala through Hue.

I run following command as it was written in http://cloudera.github.io/hue/latest/administrator/installation/starting/

```
build/env/bin/supervisor
```

then I got "No such file or directory" warning.

I also tried

```
build/env/bin/hue runserver
```

and I got the same "No such file or directory" warning because there are no such files there.

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions are written relative to Hue's installation folder, or the parent folder of the build-process output. Your error is simply saying that the relative path you're trying to use doesn't exist... Without more context, the error isn't incorrect

For a more simpler installation, you can try running the HUE docker container.